# WiX referencing an external license file

Tags: licensing, wix

I have a WiX installer that has 2 different licenses depending on who I give the installer to. I dont want to have to compile different installers though. I would rather ship the .msi file with a license.rtf file left in the filesystem. The RTF should not be included in the installer. But it should bring it up as the license agreement at install time. This way I can just change the RTF after I have compiled the installer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that build-time binding of the license text is possible (or at least, easy). However, if the choice when to show each text can be conditioned, you can have two controls with different license texts (that is both texts are built into a single MSI), and show/hide them based on the condition.

Hope this helps.